# Stream both schema and data changes from MySQL to MySQL using Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How we can stream schema and data changes along with some kind of transformations into another MySQL instance using Kafka connect source connector.

Is there a way to propagate schema changes also if I use Kafka's Python library(confluent_kafka) to consume and transform messages before loading into target DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Debezium to stream MySQL binlogs into Kafka. Debezium is built upon Kafka Connect framework.

From there, you can use whatever client you want, including Python, to consume and transform the data.

If you want to write to MySQL, you can use Kafka Connect JDBC sink connector.

Here is an old post on this topic - https://debezium.io/blog/2017/09/25/streaming-to-another-database/

Comment: I need to transform data coming from Kafka. Along with transformation I also want to make sure that whatever schema changes occur in source db must be added to target db as well.

Comment: As answered, you can use whatever you want to transform the data. Debezium and the JDBC sink connector both handle schema changes on their own. Your processing logic will need redeployed for any schema changes, and will not be automatic. For example, if you added a new column, then your code needs to be edited to include some `recordValue.get("new_field")` logic

Comment: I need to transform messages before loading into target DB. So, I believe I can't use Sink connector here as it offers very basic transformations(SMT). So, I need to use `confluent_kafka` for transformations.
I am confused how I can manage schema change along with transformations within `confluent_kafka` itself.
Or is there any other solution to manage schema change using Sink and do transformations separately using `confluent_kafka`?

Comment: What are you confused about? You can consume the data, then use the Schema Registry based serializers to produce data with differing schemas from the source. Or you can use ksqlDB to do something similar without Python